# Error while loading to kubeflow a pipeline.yaml file on local kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow-pipelines, mlops

I am trying to upload a yaml file to kubeflow UI in other to create a pipeline

I have tried using alphanumeric characters as suggested and still when I try to create the pipeline I still run into the same error. this is the error message displayed.

> Pipeline version creation failed
> {"error_message":"Failed to create a pipeline and a pipeline version: Invalid input error: pipeline's name must contain only lowercase alphanumeric characters or '-' and must start with alphanumeric characters","error_details":"Failed to create a pipeline and a pipeline version: Invalid input error: pipeline's name must contain only lowercase alphanumeric characters or '-' and must start with alphanumeric characters"}